# How to include external library?

Tags: c++

Hi i would like to include a external library call NTL. its in the path as followed:

```
#include "WinNTL-5_4_2/include/NTL/tools.h"
```

My file is key.cpp and its reside in the same folder as NTL . but when i compile, it came up with another error which is ..

```
In file included from keygen.cpp:6:0:
WinNTL-5_4_2/include/NTL/tools.h:5:24: fatal error: NTL/ctools.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

As its need another file call ctools.h, how do i includes tools.h to make ctools.h work also

I tried type

```
me@ubuntu:~/GG$ g++ keygen.cpp -o keygen -l WinNTL-5_4_2/include/
keygen.cpp:6:23: fatal error: NTL/tools.h: No such file or directory
```

but it doesnt work still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, you should try changing your `include` to:

```
#include "NTL/tools.h"
```

and make sure that `WinNTL-5_4_2/include` is in your compiler's search path for include files.

Comment: I tried this

meme@ubuntu:~/GG$ g++ keygen.cpp -o keygen -l "/home/meme/GG/WinNTL-5_4_2/include/NTL/"
keygen.cpp:6:19: fatal error: tools.h: No such file or directory

Comment: meme@ubuntu:~/GG$ g++ keygen.cpp -o keygen -L "/home/meme/GG/WinNTL-5_4_2/include"
keygen.cpp:6:23: fatal error: NTL/tools.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: Please make sure that's actually the right path. Your edit suggests there should be a `CSCI368` somewhere in there.

Comment: Look, it's hard to tell what your actual problem is when you change things continuously. Right now, I'm having a hard time trusting the output you've shown in your edit. Please recheck all your paths.

Comment: Oh sorry. meme@ubuntu:~/GG/WinNTL-5_4_2/include$ cd NTL
meme@ubuntu:~/GG/WinNTL-5_4_2/include/NTL$ pwd
/home/meme/GG/WinNTL-5_4_2/include/NTL

Comment: This is my keygen.cpp folder /home/meme/GG

Comment: `-IWinNTL-5_4_2/include`, and make sure you launch from `/home/meme/GG`, or `-I/home/meme/GG/WinNTL-5_4_2/include` and run from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the root directory as part of your project's search path for include files.  It depends on your environment exactly how to do this, but there are usually two search paths -- one for include files and another for compiled libraries.  Set that with the directory that contains the WinNTL-5_4_2 directory and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

You had to add "fullpath/WinNTL-5_4_2/include" in you include path of your compiler (either by -I for gcc or in the include path list of a visual studio project)
Expecting that ctools.h exists in ".../WinNTL-5_4_2/include/NTL"